# Why does copying the contents of a folder takes a lot of time in java

Tags: java

I wrote a code in java to copy directories using streams. The working is good, all the files are getting copied to their appropriate locations. However, the program takes a lot of time to terminate even after copying the last remaining file in the directory. I just wanted to know that is it normal or do i have to make some changes in my code. here is the code that i wrote:

```
void copy_file(File source, File dest){

        File temp_file = new File(dest.getPath()+File.separator+source.getName());
        if(!temp_file.exists()){
            temp_file.mkdir();
        }

        File[] list = source.listFiles();
        if(list.length>0){
            for(File temp:list){
                if(temp.isFile()){
                    copy(temp, temp_file);
                }
                else{
                    copy_file(temp, temp_file);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void copy(File source, File dest){
        System.out.print("\n Copying File: "+source.getName());
        try(FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(source);
            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(dest.getPath()+File.separator+source.getName())){

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;

            while((length = fin.read(buffer)) > 0){
                fout.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
            }
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `The program takes a lot of time to terminate even after copying the last remaining file in the directory.` ... how did you ascertain this?

Comment: I agree. I would first like to see *how* you came to that conclusion.

Comment: Buffered streams might help (on the other hand, who knows for sure with all the caching happening at OS-level or even at the disk/ssd-controllers). But probably worth a try.

Comment: i actually tried copying a directory via command line. even after copying the last files , the program keeps running for like 20 - 30 mins . i had to terminate the program at last

Comment: @cello i tried using buffered streams, they take even more time than this

Comment: You should write every file about to be copied to System.out. I bet there may be the current directory (".") be included or sth like that...

Comment: okay man, i will try that and update the question accordingly

Comment: works well after adding your suggestion @Florian. thanks for the advice. updated the code.